# How to change react-select color

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm unsure how to change the color from the default blue to something else. The example code is in the codesandbox link below. I tried changing the styling for root, but had no success.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ly87zo23kl

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Version 2.1.0 of `react-select` has added the option to override the theme.

Here an example of how it works:

```
<Select
    defaultValue={flavourOptions[0]}
    label="Single select"
    options={flavourOptions}
    theme={(theme) => ({
      ...theme,
      borderRadius: 0,
      colors: {
      ...theme.colors,
        text: 'orangered',
        primary25: 'hotpink',
        primary: 'black',
      },
    })}
  />
```

You can find [here](https://react-select.com/styles#overriding-the-theme) the complete documentation and live example and [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/90995cca51e59c6691d35ec2862a62bbd02f68c2/packages/react-select/src/theme.ts#L3) the different variables that can be overwritten.

Comment: In react v3, style components have confusing names: neutral0 sets background, primary25 sets highlight and neutral80 sets selected text color. Non-selected text color can be set by setting color: '#ffffff' on the parent element.

Comment: I would add that the overridden colors must have known browser names like the ones in the example, and hex colors would not work (at least in my case, hex didn't work :( )

Answer (score 2):

Tested on `react-select v5.7.4`

For changing the dropdown's background color:

```
<Select
  styles={{
    control: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      boxShadow: "none",
      border: "none",
      backgroundColor: "red",
      color: "#000000",
      width:"100%"
    })
  }}
/>
```

For Changing the dropdown option's background color as well:

```
<Select
  styles={{
    control: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      boxShadow: "none",
      border: "none",
      backgroundColor: "red",
      color: "#000000",
      width:"100%"
    }),
    option: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? '#00AEEC' : 'inherit',
    })
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd find a good and complete answer, so I started to looked inside the code of React-select and i find this:

```
   <Select
    options={options}
    menuPortalTarget={document.body}
    menuPosition="fixed"
    theme={(theme) => ({
      ...theme,
      borderRadius: 10,
      colors: {
        ...theme.colors,
        //after select dropdown option
        primary50: "gray",
        //Border and Background dropdown color
        primary: "#CAFFFA",
        //Background hover dropdown color
        primary25: "gray",
        //Background color
        neutral0: "black",
        //Border before select
        neutral20: "#CAFFCA",
        //Hover border
        neutral30: "#82FFE7",
        //No options color
        neutral40: "#CAFFCA",
        //Select color
        neutral50: "#F4FFFD",
        //arrow icon when click select
        neutral60: "#42FFDD",
        //Text color
        neutral80: "#F4FFFD",
      },
    })}
```

i know this answer is old but i hope help anyone.