# How to change options color in React-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to change the color of the options in react-select,

here is a picture for what I mean, as you see the colors are not clear

[image]

the react select code:

```
    <Select
        isMulti="true" // allow to select mutli options
        isRtl="true" // right to left
        name="name" // html name
        options={accountsNames} // options
        className="basic-multi-select"
        classNamePrefix="select"
        isSearchable="true" // searchable for the closest one
        placeholder="اختر ..." // if there is no option selected 
        styles={customStyles}
/>
```

---

**Update**

Thanks to Mr Amruth L S
it helps me to change the highlight theme, but I want to know also how to change the font color of the options in the menu

the new image, as you see the font color is white and not clear

[image]

the new code :

```
    <Select
        isMulti="true" // allow to select mutli options
        isRtl="true" // right to left
        name="name" // html name
        options={accountsNames} // options
        className="basic-multi-select"
        classNamePrefix="select"
        isSearchable="true" // searchable for the closest one
        placeholder="اختر ..." // if there is no option selected 
        theme={(theme) => ({
  ...theme,
  borderRadius: 0,
  colors: {
  ...theme.colors,
    text: '#3599B8',
    font:'#3599B8',
    primary25: '#3599B8',
    primary: '#3599B8',
    neutral80: 'black',
    color: 'black',
  },
})}
/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change react-select color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52994744/how-to-change-react-select-color)

Comment: pls refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52994744/how-to-change-react-select-color

Comment: Indeed helped me thank you, but do you know how to change the options font color in the menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can u try this.

```
const customStyles = {
  option: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    borderBottom: '1px dotted pink',
    color: state.isSelected ? 'red' : 'blue',
    padding: 20,
  })
}

<Select
        isMulti="true" // allow to select mutli options
        isRtl="true" // right to left
        name="name" // html name
        options={accountsNames} // options
        className="basic-multi-select"
        classNamePrefix="select"
        isSearchable="true" // searchable for the closest one
        placeholder="اختر ..." // if there is no option selected 
        theme={(theme) => ({
  ...theme,
  borderRadius: 0,
  colors: {
  ...theme.colors,
    text: '#3599B8',
    font:'#3599B8',
    primary25: '#3599B8',
    primary: '#3599B8',
    neutral80: 'black',
    color: 'black',
  },
})}
styles={customStyles}
/>
```